# Keep track of all running blocks

Tags: ios, swift

I have list of objects. Each of the objects contains optional image value, which needs to be dowloaded. I want to return the list after all images has been initialised(if any). Does it have anything to do with NSOPerationQueues?

```
func getFullList(list:[AnyObject], completion:(result: [AnyObject]) -> Void {
   for item in list {
      downloadImage(item.url), completion: {(image) in
      item.image = image
   )}
   // I know this does not work here
   completion(result: list)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested code.

```
func getFullList(list:[AnyObject], completion:(result: [AnyObject]) -> Void {
    let group = dispatch_group_create()

   for item in list {
        dispatch_group_enter(group)

      downloadImage(item.url), completion: {(image) in
          item.image = image

          dispatch_group_leave(group)
      }
   )}

   dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
        completion(result: list)
   }
}
```